# Несколько вопросов по vim?

Tags: vim

Открытые две вкладки, можно поменять местами: ctrl+w+r...
**Можно две вертикальные поменять на горизонтальные?**

Клавиша О (или о) создает новую строку и вход в режим редактирования.
**Есть аналогичная команда, но не входя в режим редактирования?**

Как-то наткнулся на информацию о написании макросов, командой q.
На тот момент не надо было, а сейчас не могу найти, где об этом читал.
**Как команда q работает?**
**Если не ошибаюсь, макрос действует пока не закрыл редактор?
Можно сохранять написанные макросы, что бы использовать потом?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Почти все ответы просто гуглятся.

Первый вопрос:

```
Ctrl+w, t, Ctrl+w, K
```

для перехода от вертикального расположения к горизонтальному,

```
Ctrl+w, t, Ctrl+w, H
```

для перехода от горизонтального к вертикальному,
см. на EnSO, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269603/to-switch-from-vertical-split-to-horizontal-split-fast-in-vim).

Второй:

Предлагают определить в **vimrc** команды:

```
nmap <S-Enter> O<Esc>
nmap <CR> o<Esc>
```

Или эти, чтобы после добавления новой строки остаться на прежней:

```
nmap <S-Enter> O<Esc>j
nmap <CR> o<Esc>k
```

см. [здесь](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_newline_without_entering_insert_mode).

По третьему:

Использовать можно так:

```
qa
# далее действия, которые вы хотите записать, а в конце
q
```

Вместо **a** можете использовать любую латинскую букву.

Для применения макроса для ряда строк можно воспользоваться этим:

```
Shift-V
# выделяете нужное количество строк
:norm! @a
```

тем самым вы вызовете макрос в регистре **a** для всех выделенных строк.

Для сохранения использую команду **mks**, которая, строго говоря, сохраняет не столько макрос, сколько саму сессию, в т.ч. все отрытые буферы (что зачастую и нужно):

```
:mks vim_cfg
```

В следующий раз можно загрузить сессию:

```
vim -S vim_cfg
```

Comment: По ответу на третий вопрос. Все непустые регистры сохраняются в _~/.viminfo_. См. `h: 21.3`